# QGraphicsItem::pos returns 0 when in layout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem, qlayout

I have the following Qt code fragment in my **widget.cpp**:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    m_Scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    m_Scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    GraphicsTextItem* m_1 = new GraphicsTextItem(nullptr, QString("l_1"));

    GraphicsTextItem* m_2 = new GraphicsTextItem(nullptr, QString("l_2"));


    QGraphicsLinearLayout* layout = new QGraphicsLinearLayout;
    layout->addItem(m_1);
    layout->addItem(m_2);

    QGraphicsWidget* list = new QGraphicsWidget;
    list->setLayout(layout);
    m_Scene->addItem(list);

    qDebug() << m_2->x() << " " << m_2->y(); // Prints 0,0 Why?

    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    view->setScene(m_Scene);
}
```

GraphicsTextItem is a derived class of QGraphicsWidget :

```
class GraphicsTextItem : public QGraphicsWidget
{
private:
    QString m_Name;
public:
    GraphicsTextItem(QGraphicsItem * parent = nullptr, const QString& name = QString());
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override
    {
        QFont font("Times", 12);
        painter->setFont(font);
        painter->drawText(0, 0, m_Name);
    }
};
```

I also give my short main located in **main.cpp**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

My question is that why the qDebug line prinnts me 0,0 as certainly the position of the widget is non-zero. If I don't put the widget in a layout and I call setPos() qDebug prints the correct value set previously.

Comment: what is `GraphicsTextItem`?

Comment: It is a QGraphicsWidget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial position of all QGraphicsItem is (0, 0) and that includes m_2, and m_2 will change its position when the QGraphicsLinearLayout is applied that will be an instant after the synchronous task is finished and the eventloop starts working, this can be observed using `QTimer::singleShot(0, ...)`:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{

    m_Scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    view->setScene(m_Scene);

    m_Scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    GraphicsTextItem *m_1 = new GraphicsTextItem(nullptr, QString("l_1"));

    GraphicsTextItem *m_2 = new GraphicsTextItem(nullptr, QString("l_2"));


    QGraphicsLinearLayout* layout = new QGraphicsLinearLayout;
    layout->addItem(m_1);
    layout->addItem(m_2);

    QGraphicsWidget* list = new QGraphicsWidget;
    list->setLayout(layout);
    m_Scene->addItem(list);

    qDebug() << "synchronous" << m_2->pos() << m_2->mapToScene(QPointF{});

    QTimer::singleShot(0, m_2, [m_2](){
        qDebug() << "asynchronous"<< m_2->pos() << m_2->mapToScene(QPointF{});
    });
}
```

Output:

```
synchronous QPointF(0,0) QPointF(0,0)
asynchronous QPointF(62,6) QPointF(62,6)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Is this related to the show event which is triggered just after ? In that case does exist a method to retrive the position by reference ? I ask this because I will have annother item which makes a trajectory between two GraphicsTextItems ?

Comment: @Minee It has nothing to do with the show method since the scene does not need it but the task of calculating the size of a layout is executed asynchronously through an event. The position can not be obtained by reference (in Qt the references are not used), instead you must obtain the position with the getter whenever you need, for example you can use a QTimer to obtain the position in a period of time, or simple to obtain the position when you need it, so in conclusion you have to `GraphicsTextItem * m_1` member of the class.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the answer, this really gave me headaches. **One question though:** Is it always guaranteed that, `QTimer.singleShot(0, handler)` is gonna be called after the added items are shown? Is Qt free to reorder/optimize the event loop priorities, which may lead to `singleShot` being executed before the scene update? Would it be better to somehow rely on `itemChange()` signals _(or similar)_ instead to apply logic to items once they changed position _(initially)_?

Comment: @timmwagener 1) [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details): *As a special case, a QTimer with a timeout of 0 will time out as soon as all the events in the window system's event queue have been processed.* And one of those events is the one that is shown on the screen so yes. 2) is another option.